# iPad app for offline HTML/CSS/JavaScript testing?

Tags: web-development, ios, offline, ipad-app

I often use websites like [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) or [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to do some development crash tests.

I recently got an iPad and I'm looking for an app which can provide similar HTTP/CSS/JavaScript sandbox like these websites.

I require that it allows **offline work**, **common libraries support** (like jQuery), and the best would be Ajax support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A paid solution would be [Codepad](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/codepad-html-css-js-programming/id672627288?mt=8). The price of this app is €0.89.

- Supports many libaries like jQuery
- Code highlighting
- Code hinting
- Custom programming keyboard
- Javascript console

Comment: *Offline libraries support*, that's a good suggestion! Do you know if it provides offline Ajax support too? I don't see it in the feature list...

Comment: How would you be able to send requests without a internet connection? I don't think that would be possible.

Comment: Do you know the JSFiddle ajax support? It's very basic, and I think it would be possible to embedded it on iPad. Ajax doesn't really need a internet connection (it can be done on localhost for instance), actually I think it just need a HTTP response.

Comment: You've posted two answers to this question. Please consider consolidating them into a single answer which compares their merits.

Answer (score 2):

The app "[JSpad](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jspad-javascript-html-css/id555221877?mt=8)" is what you need.

It has JS, HTML and CSS support with code highlighting.

Comment: It doesn't provide common libraries support doesn't it?

Comment: I am not sure about that, but you could use direct links to libraries like query.

Comment: Actually the major requirement is the offline functionnality.

Comment: If it doesn't match some features but matches other features you should specify what features it doesn't match with possible workaround or something similar (or just a caveat if there isn't a work around. For example see my [answer about ThunderBird](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/71/is-there-a-good-email-client-that-runs-on-both-windows-and-linux/81#81).